# MessageBox.Show being displayed too fast

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to create my own version of "Fleet battle", but I'm stuck at 99.9%. And here is why. After a ship was destroyed, its color should change to red and then a `MessageBox` "You won" or "You lost" should come. So now, if the AI destroys my last ship, everything is going fine, all the ships are becoming red one by one and then comes this "You lost" message. But in the opposite case - if I win, the AI ships are becoming red, but the last cell of the last ship becomes red after I click "OK" at the `MessageBox` "You won". I'm using the same algorithm in both cases and wondering what I'm doing wrong with it. Here is the AI part:

```
// AI hits a ship
        if ((arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield1[rowIndex, columnIndex] == "1") || (arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield1[rowIndex, columnIndex] == "2") ||
            (arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield1[rowIndex, columnIndex] == "3") || (arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield1[rowIndex, columnIndex] == "4"))
        {
            AIHuntingAShip = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = "  X";
            arrayShipsHitbyAIMap[rowIndex, columnIndex] = "  X"; // AI marks the burning enemy ships 
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

            arrayAITakenShots[transformCoordinatesToCellNumber(rowIndex, columnIndex)] = transformCoordinatesToCellNumber(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            storeRowIndex = rowIndex;
            storeColumnIndex = columnIndex;
            arrayShipsHitbyAIXY[detectedShipLength] = transformCoordinatesToCellNumber(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            detectedShipLength++;

            if (detectedShipLength == int.Parse(arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield1[rowIndex, columnIndex])) // AI destroys a ship (the array stores the length of the ship in each of the ship's cells)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < detectedShipLength; i++) // placing "   o"s around the destroyed ship
                {
                    restrictArea(int.Parse(tranformCellNumberToCoordinates(arrayShipsHitbyAIXY[i])[0].ToString()),
                                 int.Parse(tranformCellNumberToCoordinates(arrayShipsHitbyAIXY[i])[1].ToString()),
                                 dataGridView1,
                                 arrayShipsHitbyAIMap,
                                 arrayAITakenShots);
                }

                detectedShipLength = 0;
                AIHuntingAShip = false;

                playerShips--;
                textBox6.Text = playerShips.ToString();

                if (playerShips == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You lost!", "Try it again!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    dataGridView2.Enabled = false;
                }
           }
```

and here is my part:

```
// player hits a ship
        if ((arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield2[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] != null) && (arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield2[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] != "   ."))
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "  X";
            arrayShipsHitbyPlayerMap[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] = "  X";
            dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            arrayPlayerTakenShots[transformCoordinatesToCellNumber(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)] = transformCoordinatesToCellNumber(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);

            int shipIdent = int.Parse(arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield2[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex][0].ToString()); // ship ID
            int playersShipLength = int.Parse(arrayOccupiedCellsBattlefield2[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex][1].ToString()); // ship length

            arrayForPlayersShipsXY[shipIdent] += e.RowIndex.ToString() + e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + ";"; // save the coordinates of this particular ship 
            arrayForPlayerCounters[shipIdent]++;   // increase this particular cell counter basing on the "shipIdent" 

            if (arrayForPlayerCounters[shipIdent] == playersShipLength) // ship destroyed, so mark the area with "   o"
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < playersShipLength; i++)
                {
                    string xy = extractXYForPlayersShip(arrayForPlayersShipsXY[shipIdent])[i].ToString();
                    int x = int.Parse(xy.ToString()[0].ToString());
                    int y = int.Parse(xy.ToString()[1].ToString());
                    restrictArea(x, y, dataGridView2, arrayShipsHitbyPlayerMap, arrayPlayerTakenShots);
                }
                AIShips--;
                textBox7.Text = AIShips.ToString();
            }

            if (AIShips == 0)
            {
                dataGridView2.Enabled = false;                    
                MessageBox.Show("You won!", "Congrats!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: If the restrictArea is the method which is coloring the hit ship and it is an async method, or a method which is being executed on a different thread, then such a result can be expected. In that case you need to await it (synchronize it). For testing purposes, you may try to put a Thread.Sleep before the MessageBox and see what happens (not good for release).

Comment: The "restrictArea" is a method, which colors the "sea" to red and marks the area around the destoyed ship with "o". But it is not an async one. And it's on the same thread.

Comment: The question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms might seem the same, but they are not. There is a lot of repeated code, and it is hard to make sure they both do the "same thing". Try and break out parts of this code into smaller methods so you can reuse them.

Without seeing everything, I think this is the issue:

`AI`:

```
if (...) //Ship is destroyed
{
    // ...
    if (ships == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(...);
    }
}
```

`Player`

```
if (...) //ship is destroyed
{
    // ...
}

if (ships == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(...);
}
```

`MessageBox.Show` is called inside vs. outside the "ship destroyed" `if` block.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Already tried to move the parts of the code with MessageBox.Show, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As you said both algorithms are equal but windows refresh your form after you hit the 'OK' button.
So I suggest refresh it yourself before displaying msgbox.

```
        if (AIShips == 0)
        {
            dataGridView2.Refresh(); // <-------- +
            dataGridView2.Enabled = false;                    
            MessageBox.Show("You won!", "Congrats!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

Your code is a bit messy I'm not sure about the grid view name, If your problem is about the first one, try this: `dataGridView1.Refresh();`

Comment: I wish it would help, but it did not... Thank you.